# Upper bounds for the number of factors of a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, soft-question, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f(x) = a_nx^n +a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_1x+a_0$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Assuming that $f(x)$ is reducible over $Z$, can we make any comments for a non-trivial ($<n$) upper bound for the number of factors of it?

Comment: Sure: “It is impossible to give an upper bound that is strictly smaller than $n$ in general.” That is, if you wish to stick to *true* comments. Otherwise, you can make any comment you wish, though it will likely be either irrelevant or false. $a_n(x-b)^n$, $a_n,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Are we counting actual numbers as well?  As the coefficients, can be thought of as digits in a base.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: Huh?

Comment: any polynomial with an even number of odd non constant term coefficients has 2 as a factor if the constant term is even.

Comment: Consider $x^4 + x^2 + 2$. How ?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, what if $n$ is a prime number for example?

Comment: @Ninja: It doesn’t matter: you can’t say anything in general, because a polynomial of degree $n$ may be fully reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, even if $n$ is prime. I mean, just multiply $p$ linear factors with integer coefficients. Now, it may be possible to say that a **particular** polynomial has fewer factors, but that was not what you asked. When you say “Consider $x^4+x^2+2$”, you are completely changing the question, so that’s a non sequitur to the issue you raised to begin with.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Okay then, can you state some theorems to check (ir)reducibility of a polynomial like Eisenstein's criterion, please?

Comment: That would be a completely different question, so you should ask it separately. Here you are asking about the number of factors in a *reducible* polynomial. By the way, in fact a polynomial of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ can have arbitrarily many irreducible factors, because the content may have arbitrarily many irreducible factors. Though primitive polynomial (content $1$) have at most $n$, and that's the best you can say.

Answer (score 1):

Not only can you not say anything about such a polynomial having fewer than $n$ factors in general, *you can’t even say it has at most $n$ irreducible factors!*

As a consequence of Gauss’s Lemma, we know that the factorization of a polynomial with integer coefficients into irreducible factors will be of the form
$$f(x) = p_1\cdots p_kq_1(x)\cdots q_r(x)$$
where $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ are prime numbers, and $q_1,\ldots,q_r$ are polynomials of degree at least one that are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ *and* have trivial content; that is, the gcd of their coefficients is $1$.

We can certainly say that $r\leq n$ (but we cannot in general say whether it will be strictly less than $n$), but we can put no bounds on $k$. That is, $f(x)$ can have arbitrarily many irreducible factors in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. For example, $7^Nx$ has $N+1$ irreducible factors, and is of degree $1$.

*Primitive* polynomials (polynomials with trivial content, as they are called in Number Theory [but not in Computer Science]) will have $k=0$, so we will have at most $\deg(f)$ irreducible factors; however, we have no way of bounding this number to anything *less* than $\deg(f)$ in general. Of course, one may take a particular polynomial and see whether it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ (sundry tests exist for that), but that is not a way to bound the number of factors in general, which is what this question asks.